# Stopping time that is not a reaching time?

Tags: stopping-times

For example, let $X=\left(X_t\right)_{t\ge0}$ a right-continuous random process, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $T_x = \inf\left\{t\ge0\;;\; X_t\ge x\right\}$.

The random variable $T_x$ is a stopping time that is also a "reaching time". What would look like a stopping time that is not built in such a way ?

Comment: Another stopping time:$T\equiv t_0$.

Comment: I don't know if you count this as an example, but you might also consider $\tau=\inf \{t\geq 0| \exists s\leq t: X_t=X_s\},$ i.e., the first time that the process turns around. In higher dimensions, this is the first time the process closes a loop.

Comment: Sure... The question wasn't well formulated.

Comment: Note that in $1-d$, the above is only a stopping time if your filtration is right-continuous.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I have never met this one ! It answers the question...